# Is it possible to query the nthChild with DOMDocument?

Tags: dom, xpath

```
$html = '<div id="animal"><p class="dog"> pudal </p> <p class="dog">chiwawa </p> </div>';
$qry = '//div[@class="animal"]/p[@class="dog"]/text();
```

> how to get chiwawa or pudal only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this xpath

```
//div[@id = 'animal']/p[2]/text()
```